# R ggplot facet lookup labeller

Tags: r, ggplot2

What's the syntax for using a data frame as a lookup table for facet labels (https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/labeller.html)?
For example:

```
require(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(value = c(1,3), variable = letters[c(1,3)])
labels <- data.frame(variable = letters[1:3], label = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"))
```

Here's a failed attempt:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = "x", y = value)) + geom_col() + facet_grid( ~ variable, labeller = as_labeller(labels))
```

Comment: Unless there's a reason why you can't, you might want to just join the data frames so you have `label` as a column of `df`, then facet by that.

Comment: @camille yes, but if the data are large and reused later for other purposes it's a less attractive option.

Answer (score 1):

you want a named character vector

```
labels <- data.frame(variable = letters[1:3], 
                     label = c("Apple", "Banana", "Cherry"),
                     stringsAsFactors = F)
ggplot(df, aes(x = "x", y = value)) + geom_col() +
  facet_grid( ~ variable, labeller = as_labeller(with(labels, setNames(label, variable))))
```